# Merge header columns in a matrix in bash

Tags: bash, matrix

I want to merge the headers of the matrix:

```
    12  12  12  13
bb  2   
cc      1               
aa          5
ee              6
```

like this:

```
        12     13
bb      2        
cc      1        
aa      5        
ee              6
```

I tried this and it didn't work (and it wasn't actually applicable to the larger matrix:

```
merged_headers=()
for i in {1..3}; do
    header=$(head -1 unmerge.txt | awk -v col=$i '{print $col}')
    if [ -z "$header" ]; then
        header=${merged_headers[-1]}
    else
        merged_headers+=($header)
    fi
    sed -i "s/^[ \t]*$/$header/g" unmerge.txt
done
```

Comment: What's your input field separator? Multiple spaces or one tab?

Comment: input Field Separator is tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- columns are consolidated in a left-to-right order
- if the column headers are `13 12 14 12 13 14` then the new column headers will be (left-to-right) `13 12 14` (as opposed to a numeric or string ordering that would generate `12 13 14`)
- the consolidated data set will have at most one non-empty value per unique column header; otherwise we'll append them together into a single string; if multiple values are guaranteed to be numeric we could modify the code to sum the values

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t"
        newcolno=1
      }
      { printf "%s", $1                                       # print 1st column

        if (NR==1) {                                          # if header record ...
           for (old=2; old<=NF; old++) {                      # loop through columns ...
               if (! ($old in newcol)) {                      # looking for new header and if found ...
                  printf "%s%s", OFS, $old                    # print to stdout and ...
                  newcol[$old]= ++newcolno                    # make note of the new column number to map to
               }
               old2new[old]= newcol[$old]                     # map current column number to new column number
           }
        }
        else {                                                # non-header rows
           delete row                                         # clear our new output array

           for (old=2; old<=NF; old++)                        # loop through current columns ...
               row[old2new[old]]=row[old2new[old]] $old       # append value to new row/column

           for (new=2; new<=newcolno; new++)                  # loop through new row/columns and ...
               printf "%s%s", OFS, row[new]                   # print to stdout
        }

        print ""                                              # terminate current line
      }
' unmerge.txt
```

This generates:

```
        12      13
bb      2
cc      1
aa      5
ee              6
```

Testing a larger file to demonstrate some of our assumptions:

```
$ cat unmerge2.txt
        12      12      12      13      12      13
bb      2
cc              1
aa                      5
ee                              6
ff                              17      87                # distinct headers so no problems
gg                              100             -3        # both have header "13" so we'll append the strings
```

The `awk` script generates:

```
        12      13
bb      2
cc      1
aa      5
ee              6
ff      87      17
gg              100-3
```

Once OP is satisified with the results, and assuming OP still wants to update/overwrite the input file with the new results:

- if using `GNU awk` you can add `-i inplace` to facilitate an inplace update of the input file: `awk -i inplace 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"; newcolno=1}...' unmerge.txt`
- otherwise OP can direct the output to a tmp file and then overwrite the source file with the tmp file: `awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"; newcolno=1}...' unmerge.txt > tmpfile; mv tmpfile unmerge.txt`

Comment: Thank you. Can I add a condition like if in a row there are two values, don't merge. For example in first row there is 2 in 1st col and 7 in 2nd col. Then don't merge these two columns but merge the 3rd column.

Comment: you raise 2 issues ... 1) if `2` and `7` have the same header then which to show in the final output under that 1 consolicated header column? ... 2) what's in the 3rd column and under what header is it located (and thus what final header to be 'merge' under)?  at this point I'm not following your question and since it appears (to me) to diverge a good bit from the original question I'd suggest asking a new question (making sure to include a new set of inputs/outputs that demonstrate the new requirement)